# What is the effective way to find objects from two arrays with common key Property?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the effective way to find the objects from array2 which has a common property Value between ArrayA and ArrayB

Find All objects in Array B with ID value in Key of ArrayB

```
var ArrayA = [
              {"ID":"1","ID_DESC":"Test_DESC 1"},
              {"ID":"2","ID_DESC":"Test_DESC 2"},
              {"ID":"3","ID_DESC":"Test_DESC 3"}
             ];

var ArrayB = [
              {"KEY":"1","KEYDESC":"ID property NAME IS DIFFERENT HERE"},
              {"KEY":"20","KEYDESC":"ID NAME IS DIFFERENT HERE "},
              {"KEY":"30","KEYDESC":"ID3 NAME IS DIFFERENT HERE"},
              {"KEY":"40","KEYDESC":"ID4 NAME IS DIFFERENT HERE"}
             ];

var CommonArray = [
                   {"KEY":"1","KEYDESC":"ID NAME IS DIFFERENT HERE"}
                  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try intersectionBy from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#intersectionBy)

Or a quick & dirty function:

```
function intersectBy(param1, param2, property) {
this.output = [];

var p1l = param1.length,
    p2l = param2.length;
for (var i = 0; i < p1l; i++) {
    var currentI = param1[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < p2l; j++){
        var currentJ = param2[j];
        if (currentI && currentI[property] && currentJ && currentJ[property] && currentI[property] === currentJ[property]) {
            this.output.push(currentI);
        }
    }
}
return this.output;
}
```

Comment: is there something is JS without use of library ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and filter the second array.

```js
var array1 = [{ ID: "1", ID_DESC: "Test_DESC 1" }, { ID: "2", ID_DESC: "Test_DESC 2" }, { ID: "3", ID_DESC: "Test_DESC 3" }],
    array2 = [{ KEY: "1", KEYDESC: "ID property NAME IS DIFFERENT HERE" }, { KEY: "20", KEYDESC: "ID NAME IS DIFFERENT HERE " }, { KEY: "3", KEYDESC: "ID3 NAME IS DIFFERENT HERE" }, { KEY: "40", KEYDESC: "ID4 NAME IS DIFFERENT HERE" }],
    result = function (array1, array2) {
        var hash = Object.create(null);
        array1.forEach(function (a) { hash[a.ID] = true; });
        return array2.filter(function (a) { return hash[a.KEY]; });
    }(array1, array2);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

or with ES6 a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
var array1 = [{ ID: "1", ID_DESC: "Test_DESC 1" }, { ID: "2", ID_DESC: "Test_DESC 2" }, { ID: "3", ID_DESC: "Test_DESC 3" }],
    array2 = [{ KEY: "1", KEYDESC: "ID property NAME IS DIFFERENT HERE" }, { KEY: "20", KEYDESC: "ID NAME IS DIFFERENT HERE " }, { KEY: "30", KEYDESC: "ID3 NAME IS DIFFERENT HERE" }, { KEY: "40", KEYDESC: "ID4 NAME IS DIFFERENT HERE" }],
    result = array2.filter((s => a => s.has(a.KEY))(new Set(array1.map(a => a.ID))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Using the first option gives 1 array as result everytime without the checks on array 2. using option 2 facing > is not valid error

Comment: @Viru, in the first example, i have changed `array2`, now you get two items in the result set. what exactly is not working?